# PHPGrid override delete to expire a record instead of delete it

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use phpgrid for an admin editing interface. The tables I am working on are designed to store historical values. So in this case I have a school it has a datetime for when it was created and when it was expired. PHPgrid handles CRUD services, however I don't want it to delete a record, rather I want it to update the end date with the current date and time instead.

does anyone know how to do this with PHPGrid?

Comment: Have you tried looking through the codebase for `DELETE FROM` or such SQL query and then just override the behavior?

Comment: I am hoping at first to now have to alter the code base and see if there is something native I can do. As altering a 3rd party library would be more difficult to support long term with updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately to do this I added a loadComplete function that did an unbind to the click event for the delete button, then added my own event function and ajax call. not ideal but it works.

```
        $onGridLoadComplete = <<<ONGRIDLOADCOMPLETE
    function(status, rowid)
    {
        $("#del_school").unbind('click');   
        $("#del_school").click(function(){

            if($(".ui-state-highlight").attr("id") != undefined){
                if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")){

                    var id = $(".ui-state-highlight").attr("id"); 

                    $.ajax({
                      url: "/phpgrid-ext/index.php?faction=expireSchool&id="+id
                    }).done(function() {
                      $("#refresh_school").trigger("click");
                    });


                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Please select a record to delete.");
            }

            return false;
            });
    }
ONGRIDLOADCOMPLETE;

$dg2->add_event("jqGridLoadComplete", $onGridLoadComplete);
```

Comment: I found a better answer. You can set a different save script through the following function set_jq_editurl("/admin/jqgrid/editSchool"); then inside that file you need to setup a switch for the request variable oper which will have the following values add|edit|del and then use the "id" request field for your primary key. Finally all the other fields will be passed in by the name pulled from the database. This allows you to do custom save logic.